# Is loc an optional attribute when searching dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Both the following lines seem to give the same output:

```
df1 = df[df['MRP'] > 1500]
df1 = df.loc[df['MRP'] > 1500]
```

Is loc an optional attribute when searching dataframe?

Comment: What do you mean "Is loc an optional attribute when searching dataframe"? In both examples you're either _filtering_ or _selecting_ from a dataframe. The "search" occurs in the creation of the Boolean Index `df['MRP'] > 1500`. If the question is, is `loc` optional when selecting data from a DataFrame the answer to that is, of course, yes and no. There is flexibility in `loc` that you won't find from standard `__getitem__` but there is significant overlap on simple conditions.

Comment: `loc` gives you some extra functionalities, for example selecting certain columns: `df.loc[df['MRP'] > 1500, ['ColA', 'ColB']]`. Or if you want to assign values in a certain column after selecting: `df.loc[df['MRP'] > 1500, 'ColA'] = 10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coming from [`Padas.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas-dataframe-loc) documentation:

> Access a group of rows and columns by label(s) or a boolean array.
>
> .loc[] is primarily label based, but may also be used with a boolean
> array.

When you are using Boolean array to filter out data, `.loc` is optional, and in your example `df['MRP'] > 1500` gives a Series with the values of truthfulness, so it's not necessary to use `.loc` in that case.

```py
df[df['MRP']>15]
    MRP cat
0    18   A
3    19   D
6    18   C
```

But if you want to access some other columns where this Boolean Series has True value, then you may use `.loc`:

```py
df.loc[df['MRP']>15, 'cat']
0     A
3     D
6     C
```

Or, if you want to change the values where the condition is `True`:

```py
df.loc[df['MRP']>15, 'cat'] = 'found'
```